# Click error on a clusterer within a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm trying to handle the click event on a `MarkerClusterer` (v1.0) within a Google Map (v3) in order to zoom on the clusterer's center.

## The problem

When the user clicks on a clusterer, the following error is shown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> at Cluster.getBounds (markerclusterer.js:903)
>
> at ClusterIcon.triggerClusterClick (markerclusterer.js:1057)
>
> at HTMLDivElement. (markerclusterer.js:1082)
>
> Cluster.getBounds @ markerclusterer.js:903
>
> ClusterIcon.triggerClusterClick @ markerclusterer.js:1057
>   (anonymous) @ markerclusterer.js:1082

This line, present in the `MarkerClusterer`'s function `getBounds()`, seems bound to this bug:

`for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {`

## Sources

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('storemap'), {
    center: {lat: parseFloat(defaultLat), lng: parseFloat(defaultLong)},
    disableDefaultUI:false,
    fullscreenControl:false,
    streetViewControl:true,
    zoom: 8, 
    styles : mapstyles
});


mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {styles: clusterStyles});
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    map.setCenter(cluster.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+3);
});
```

## My question

How can I fix the error when the user clicks on a clusterer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to add a custom `clusterclick` event on marker cluster.

Remove the  `clusterclick` listener.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    map.setCenter(cluster.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+3);
});
```

Just keep the MarkerClusterer initialization code.

```
mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {styles: clusterStyles});
```

When you click on the cluster it will automatically zoom in as well as center on the cluster. You can find the [MarkerClusterer Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) while illustrates the same.

Comment: What if you want to modify the default click behavior? i.e., more / less zoom, change map type, etc. How can you use a custom listener without the error?